# Port to send to self

Tags: port

A few years ago, I was working on a application that would communicate between computers using direct connect. I recall that there was a port I would send to when I was wanting to test using only one computer. This port would treat the packet as if it was being sent to the computer from another computer or... something.

I apologize for being somewhat vague, but I am not recalling the specific details of what it was I had done. I just recall that it was very convenient for testing purposes. I would run the application twice, and have one act as a server and the other as a client. They would both be sending from different ports, but would both send to the same 'local' port... Or something like that.

Anyone know what I'm talking about? I want to know what port number this would be. I believe it was reserved for such use.

Thank you,
Jonathan

Comment: Talk to the host specified by `::1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asking for the "String" address localhost that you can use when creating a Socket in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Ports are for communications between applications on same or different hosts.
When your host acts as a client, it can decide to send to any ports. If your host acts as a server, the server program may be configured to listen on a range of ports.

Interfaces are for different hosts to identify each other. One host may have multiple interfaces.
Your host should have a loop back interface with ip 127.0.0.1, very convenient for testing local traffic. Suppose you have started a Tomcat server on port 8080, then you may access web applications running on your own server through

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/your_app
```

Suppose you want your host to access itself through another interface, like 192.168.1.1 that commonly represent a node on a local network, you may likewise access your app through

```
http://192.168.1.1:8080/your_app
```

If you fail to load your web page, reasons may include:

1. Your firewall (Windows) or iptables (Linux) disallows inbound traffic to port 8080.
2. Your server is not listening on this interface ip address 192.168.1.1.

For the 1st reason, you may add a rule in your Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to allow inbound traffic to the particular port or particular application (Windows), or add a line to the /etc/sysconfig/iptables (Linux).

For the 2nd reason, check on the server configuration files (e.g. For Tomcat, it is in server.xml).

Hope the information helps.